# Conflicting types for 'function' and implicit declaration of function 'function' is invalid in C99

Tags: c, xcode

The other answers on these questions say to declare the function either in a header file or before main() but I have both of these and it still doesn't work.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef WORK
#define WORK

#define TRACING true
#define DIMENSION 4
#define TOUR_LENGTH 15

void trace(char *s); //error here "Conflicting types for 'trace'"

#endif
```

^that is the header file

```
void trace(char *s) //error here "Conflicting types for 'trace'"
{
    if (TRACING)
    {
        printf("%s\n",s);
    }
}
```

^the function in question. the function is used multiple times in other .c files all with #include work.h

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "work.h"
#include "gameTree.h"
#include "gameState.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>


/*
    *   trace
    *   Provide trace output.
    *   Pre-condition: none
    *   Post-condition: if trace output is desired then the given String
    *                   parameter is shown on the console
    *   Informally: show the given message for tracing purposes
    *
    *   param s the String to be displayed as the trace message
*/
void trace(char *s) //error here "Conflicting types for 'trace'"
{
    if (TRACING)
    {
        printf("%s\n",s);
    }
}


/*
*   intro
*   Provide introductory output.
*   Pre-condition: none
*   Post-condition: an introduction to the progrm has been displayed
*   Informally: give the user some information about the program
*/
void intro()
{
    printf("Knight's Tour\n");
    printf("=============\n");
    printf("Welcome to the Knight's Tour.  This is played on a(n) %d x %d board.  The\n",DIMENSION,DIMENSION);
    printf("knight must move %d times without landing on the same square twice.\n",TOUR_LENGTH);
    printf("\n");
}


/*
*   main
*   Program entry point.
*   Pre-condition: none
*   Post-condition: the solution to the Knight's Tour will be found
*                   and displayed
*   Informally: solve the Knight's Tour
*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
gameTree g,a;   // whole game tree and solution game tree
    gameState s;    // initial game state
    stack k,r;      // stack for intermediate DF use and for tracing solution
    queue q;        // queue for intermediate BF use

    // give introduction
    intro();

    // initialise data structures
    init_stack(&k);
    init_queue(&q);
    init_gameState(&s, 1, 1);   // start at top left-hand corner: (1,1)

    // show initial board
    printf("\nStarting board:\n");
    showGameState(s);
    printf("\n");

    // solve
    init_gameTree(&g, false, s, 1);
    a = buildGameDF(g, k, TOUR_LENGTH);     // Depth-first
    //a = buildGameBF(g, q, TOUR_LENGTH);   // Breadth-first

    // show results
    if (isEmptyGT(a))
    {
        printf("No solution!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // re-trace solution from leaf to root
        init_stack(&r);
        do
        {
            push(r, a);
            a = getParent(a);
        } while (!isEmptyGT(a));

        // display move list
        while (!isEmptyS(r))
        {
            a = (gameTree)top(r);
            s = (gameState)getData(a);
            printf("Move %d: (%d,%d)\n", getLevel(a), getRow(s), getColumn(s));
            pop(r);
        }

        // display final path
        printf("\nFinal board:\n");
        showGameState(s);
    }
```

^the whole main() and .c file, the errors occur mainly in the other supplementary files with the ADT definitions such as:

```
gameTree getParent(gameTree t)
{
    gameTree p;

    trace("getParent: getParent starts"); //error here "Conflicting types for 'trace'" and "Implicit declaration of function 'trace' is invalid in C99"

    if (isEmptyGT(t))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getParent: empty game tree");
        exit(1);
    }

    init_gameTree(&p, true, NULL, -1);
    p->root = getTNParent(t->root);

    trace("getParent: getParent ends"); //error here "Conflicting types for 'trace'" and "Implicit declaration of function 'trace' is invalid in C99"
    return p;
}
```

^an example of where the trace function is called.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "tNode.h"
#include "gameTree.h"
#include "work.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

^the imports for one of the ADT .c files

So yeah I don't know what to do.

To clarify work.h and work.c are the main files for this project.

```
void setChild(gameTree t, gameTree c)
{
    trace("setChild: setChild starts"); //error here "Implicit declaration of function 'trace' is invalid in C99"    
    setTNChild(t->root, c->root);

    trace("setChild: setChild ends"); //but not here
}


void setTNSibling(tNode t, tNode n)
{
    trace("setTNSibling: setTNSibling starts"); //both errors here

    t->sibling = n;

    trace("setTNSibling: setTNSibling ends"); //only the "Implicit declaration of function 'trace' is invalid in C99" error here
}
```

I can't determine what is causing certain errors but if it were to do with importing incorrect header files shouldn't it be consistent all the way through?

I should also note that these files were given to me to use so I didn't write the original trace function.

Comment: You seem to have left out your `main.cpp`, and with it, both the `#include` list and the specific usage that is flagging the warning you state. If you think they're not relevant, think again. For all we know the function call puking the warning is `printf` because you neglected to include `stdio.h`.

Comment: Does perhaps any other of the included files `#define` `WORK`?

Comment: Thanks for the update. On which *specific* line is the warning being issued? Stick a comment noting that line in your source listing of your question. And you're *sure* (a) the `work.h` file included is the one you intend, (b) `WORK` is not already defined *before* including `work.h` in some source file, and (c) any file that uses `trace` is including `work.h` *before* using said-function ? Check all .h files *you* authored and make sure `WORK` isn't used as some other header file's include-guard fencepost.

Comment: What is the error message? Also give complete code source, not splitted includes and code. Exact content of files is mandatory in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your code samples whether `<ncurses.h>` is included or not in some of your source files.  There is a function `trace` already defined in `<ncurses.h>` on MacOS:

```
/usr/include/curses.h:1710:extern NCURSES_EXPORT(void) trace (const unsigned int);
```

If this is the actual problem, you need to rename your `trace` function to something else.

From the context, you should probably use a macro `TRACE(...)` that expands to a call to `fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)` unless you compile for the release build in which case it would expand to nothing at all.

Another potential cause for warnings is the prototype:

```
void trace(char *s);
```

Passing a string constant for a `char *` argument may cause a warning.  Since `trace` does not modify the contents of the string argument, it should be declared `const char *`.  Fix this by modifying the prototype:

```
void trace(const char *s);
```